# Node-red get Modbus TCP Read state change

Tags: node-red

Is there a way to get Modbus Read Node state change? The node has an "activity label" thet shows the state (reading, polling, error, timeout etc..) is there a way to get it as a msg.payload?

[image: Here an example of the Modbus Read node with the "activity label" in bottom left corner]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Status node, it is part of the code set of nodes and should allow you to select the node you are interested in and receive the updates to it's status.

[image: Node-red Status node]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hardillb didn't know about that node! I have just made a simple but useful flow for Modbus status management with a trigger that sends an output just if error time is > reading time. This is the flow:

```
[{"id":"f2ad55d5.52afe8","type":"status","z":"e34a61f.64e60a","name":"modbus status","scope":["b294ab2d.91ac88"],"x":323,"y":545,"wires":[["14f7bc93.c66a23"]]},{"id":"14f7bc93.c66a23","type":"function","z":"e34a61f.64e60a","name":"Parse error","func":"var status = msg.status.text;\n\nvar error = false;\n\nmsg = {};\n\nstatus = status.split(\" \");\n\nswitch(status[0]){\n    case \"timeout\":\n    case \"EMPTY\":\n    case \"error\":\n    case \"waiting\":\n        error = true;\n}\n\nif(!error)\nmsg.reset = 1; //reset the trigger, no errors\n\nelse \nmsg.payload = true; //start trigger\n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":566,"y":547,"wires":[["a740b015.432ca"]]},{"id":"a740b015.432ca","type":"trigger","z":"e34a61f.64e60a","op1":"","op2":"{ \"status\": 400 }","op1type":"nul","op2type":"json","duration":"2000","extend":false,"units":"ms","reset":"","name":"Trigger error","x":786.5,"y":547,"wires":[["e82e77fe.eb8948"]]},{"id":"e82e77fe.eb8948","type":"debug","z":"e34a61f.64e60a","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":1007,"y":549,"wires":[]}]
```